# Ruby on Rails -- assign a value to a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to assign a value to a checkbox. The code below doesn't seem to work

```
Same Section <%= f.check_box :LSU_TYPE,  :value =>"Same Section" %>
```

Instead of storing 'Same Section' in the table, value '1' is stored when i check the box.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A checkbox is a boolean field. It can only accept 1 or 0, 'True' or 'False'.

Comment: -1 Not sure why this answer was accepted, A checkbox is just a way to select something, and that something may have any value. As per [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/check_box): "The checked_value defaults to 1 while the default unchecked_value is set to 0 which is convenient for boolean values"; however, any _string_ value can be provided for both (as in @suely's example).

Answer (score 1):

@Kum this works for me:

```
<div><%= f.label :pay_with_card? %></br>
<%= f.check_box :pay_with_card,{}, "Yes", "No"%>
```

good luck!